# Using xsl:value-of in xsl:template 's

Tags: xslt, velocity, xsl-fo

I am passing an xml file to my fo file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <activityExport>
    <resourceKey>
    <key>monthName</key>
    <value>January</value>
    </resourceKey>
```

So if I directly use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"/>
```

I can see "January" in my PDF file just fine.

However, if I use it like this in a template I have:

```
<xsl:template name="format-month">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="month" select="format-number(substring($date,6,2), '##')"/>
    <xsl:param name="format" select="'m'"/>
    <xsl:param name="month-word">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 1"><xsl:value-of select="activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Then I do not see "January" when I call:

```
<xsl:variable name="monthName">
    <xsl:call-template name="format-month">
    <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'M'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="month" select="@monthValue"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($monthName,' ',@yearValue)"/>
```

I know my template works because if I have a static string in:

```
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 1">Januaryyy</xsl:when>
```

Then I can see Januaryyyy fine.

So the template works, the resource exists, but the value-of-select does not work inside of call-template or xsl:choose or xsl:when test

Any help?
Regards!

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire XML you are trying to transform? Without that, it's hard to know why the XPath doesn't find what you want.

Comment: Additionally, the parameters to `xsl:value-of` are invalid in your template. It should read `<xsl:value-of select="activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"/>`

Comment: @BenL Regarding your first comment, I will soon. However, when I try <xsl:value-of="activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"/> I can see the value just fine, so the value is definetly in the XML.

Regarding your second comment, that is a miskate I made only asking the question. I have edited it.

Comment: @BenL I will try creating a better question with a simple example later. The file I am working with is quite big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is probably fine, except that you are calling it from an unsuitable position in your XML. Therefore, the XPath you are using to set `month-word` does not find anything - it is a path to nothing.

For example, the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="format-month">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="month" select="format-number(substring($date,6,2), '##')"/>
    <xsl:param name="format" select="'m'"/>
    <xsl:param name="month-word">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$month = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:value-of select="$month-word"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="monthName">
      <xsl:call-template name="format-month">
        <xsl:with-param name="month" select=" '1' "/>
        <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'M'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($monthName,' ',@yearValue)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this XML:

```
<activityExport>
  <resourceKey>
    <key>monthName</key>
    <value>January</value>
  </resourceKey>
</activityExport>
```

produces this output:

```
January
```

Note that I have replaced the `month` parameter to your template with the value `1`. No elements in this input XML have a `@monthValue` attribute (which is what lead me to believe you are calling the template from an unsuitable location) and so `month-word` would not get set either because of the `xsl:choose`.

To make things work with your real input XML, you could try replacing the XPath with `"//activityExport/resourceKey[key='monthName']/value"` where the double-slash defines a path to *anywhere* within the XML document. This should be fine if there is only one `activityExport` node. Otherwise, you will need to work out the suitable XPath.